# How to format a list using regex

Tags: regex, macos, shell, sed

I cannot figure out how to make this work:

I have:

`icon-braille icon-bookmark-empty icon-blogger icon-adult icon-address-book`

And I want:

`'icon-braille','icon-bookmark-empty','icon-blogger','icon-adult','icon-address-book'`

Comment: Match `\s+`, then replace by `','`, and insert `'` at start and end.

Comment: To put that in to pseudo code: `replaced_str = "'" + orig_str.replace("\s+", "','") + "'";`

Comment: Why are you doing this?  What are you trying to achieve?  Are you trying to make a CSV-format file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `OSX` friendly `sed "s/ /','/g;s/^/'/;s/$/'/"`:

```
$ echo "icon-braille icon-bookmark-empty" | sed "s/ /','/g;s/^/'/;s/$/'/" 
'icon-braille','icon-bookmark-empty'
```

Comment: Didn't work. I got this output icon-'raille,icon-'ookmark-empty

Comment: @Daniel I see you are using Mac, I have added a Mac friendly version.

Answer (score 1):

With shell and sed:

```
echo "'"$(sed "s/ /','/g")"'"
```

Example:

```
$ echo "'"$(sed "s/ /','/g")"'"
icon-braille icon-bookmark-empty icon-blogger icon-adult icon-address-book
'icon-braille','icon-bookmark-empty','icon-blogger','icon-adult','icon-address-book'
```

The first line was inserted, the second — produced.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ echo "icon-braille icon-bookmark-empty icon-blogger icon-adult icon-address-book" | sed -e "s/ \+/','/g" -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/"
'icon-braille','icon-bookmark-empty','icon-blogger','icon-adult','icon-address-book'
```

Comment: Didn't work on my Mac. The output was 

'icon-braille icon-bookmark-empty icon-blogger icon-adult icon-address-book'

Comment: @Daniel looks like your implementation of sed doesn't `-e` option to specify multiple scripts. Using `;` as the separator (as indicated by sudo_O works on my Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the shell (assuming bash)

```
$ list="icon-braille icon-bookmark-empty icon-blogger icon-adult icon-address-book"
$ result=""; sep=""
$ for word in $list; do result+=$sep\'$word\'; sep=,; done
$ echo "$result"
'icon-braille','icon-bookmark-empty','icon-blogger','icon-adult','icon-address-book'
```